# JavaScript Redirect Concatenating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page www.junk.com that has an input to put an ID, then hit submit. When that button is clicked, the following JavaScript executes:

```
var host = "";

var Go = {

onReady: function() {

    $(document).on("click", ".event-submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(".event-id").val();
        window.location.replace(host + "event/" + id);
    });

    $(".event-id").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var id = $(".event-id").val();
            window.location.replace(host + "event/" + id);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

};

$(document).ready(Go.onReady);
```

This then takes the user to `www.junk.com/event/1234`

This is good, it's what I want!

On that new page, `www.junk.com/event/1234` there's that same input/submit so the user can do the same exact search for a new event. The problem is that this time, using the same JavaScript, the url becomes:

`www.junk.com/event/event/5678`

Any ideas on how I can use the same exact JavaScript function, but that will be consistent? This is going to a controller so would it be better to instead pass the data, (event id), to the controller another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you set `host`?

Comment: seems that `host` isn't what you want it to be ..where does it come from?

Comment: Updated question with more accurate representation. `host` is for me to easily set when going between localhost and web host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute path without host if host is always the same: `window.location.replace("/event/" + id)`

Comment: Ah, simply adding a `/` in the front did it. And as @Goblinlord mentioned with some more specifics. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

A djxak has mentioned you should use the absolute path instead of the relative path.  When you do end up using the "host" var you should ensure you have no trailing slash if you use an absolute path after that (with a leading slash).  The leading slash in "/event/" indicates that it should go to /event/ starting at the root.  Without a leading slash it indicates it should go to a relative location.

At `asdf.com/abcd/1234/qwerty` the root would be `asdf.com`.  A relative location will remove anything after the last slash (leaving you with `asdf.com/abcd/1234/`) then adding the relative location.

Example current location: `asdf.com/abcd/1234/qwerty`

Relative location: `x/y/z`

`asdf.com/abdc/1234/ + x/y/z
Result: asdf.com/abcd/1234/x/y/z`

Absolute location: `/x/y/z`

`asdf.com + /x/y/z
Result: asdf.com/x/y/z`